# Node webkit: How to open external link with system default browser in MAC

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, node-webkit

In windows I was using these lines

```
gui = require('nw.gui');

//To open a website externally
gui.Shell.openExternal(URL);

//To execute command line
gui.Shell.openItem(commandString);
```

Its working properly. The same piece of code is not working in MAC. What am i missing here? I dont want to create any file and write commands in it (batch file, which is usually called a shell script.). Is there a way without creating batch file and run these commands in MAC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you provide the complete portion of code you are testing ?

The following snippet works fine on OSX (tested with `nw.js 0.12.0`):

```js
var gui = require('nw.gui');
gui.Shell.openExternal('http://www.google.com');
```

Also, the `gui.Shell.openItem` command is not made to execute commands (see the [Shell documentation](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Shell)).

You should rather use the [`child_process`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) module shipped with nodejs:

```js
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec(commandString, function (error, stdout, stderr)
{
    console.log('stdout:' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr:' + stderr);
});
```